# MVVM WPF Heavy Setters

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a CRUD heavy database application. I want to be able to consistently display complex, cross property validation results.

That lead me to an approach where i have completely standard models, no INotifyPropertyChanged implemented. And ViewModels wrapping around them, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyDataErrorInfo.

I have to use a wrapper, because if i put the logic in the model, it leads to insane initiation load times. I often need a quick list of customers for lookups, comboboxes etc.

It works really well, but it requires an enormous amount of boilerplate code. All my models, think offer or customer, have 20-50 properties. All of these then have a corresponding wrapper viewmodel with the same amount of properties.

An example of ONE viewmodel property looks like this.

```
[OptionalAttribute(Name="differentName")]
public property amount {
    get => GetProperty(() => amount);
    set {
         SetProperty(() => amount, value);
         Model.amount = amount;
         ValidateAndFire(Model);
    }
```

I'm wondering if there is a different approach? I do not hate it at all, it works well, but before i commit to it for the rest of the project i'd like to explore other options.

Comment: Are you showing a property of your model or viewmodel here? Can you show the code for SetProperty and GetProperty? Why putting validation logic in your model creates bigger loading time than putting it in the viewmodel?

Comment: Thats a vm property. GetProperty and SetProperty are just implementations of INotifyPropertyChanged from devexpress MVVM Framework. It takes a lot longer to load, because i need to load ALL the models for search functionality, but i only need to load ONE viewModel at a time.

Comment: It's common to copy properties from a model object to a viewmodel and back to a model to update/insert. Either using reflection or a pre built solution eg automapper. That then keeps both classes cleaner. You can manipulate data as you do this which offers another place to put logic. This is then nice and clear if you have logic across properties etc. I've seen a t4 template used to generate the base code for viewmodels.

Comment: From an architectural point of view, it sounds like maybe you need to revisit how you’re doing search. Loading up all models to do search is an “architectural smell” to me. Is there maybe a better way?

Comment: @Keithernet Im just loading all the data from a database and display it in a grid which then has all kinds of search and filter options.
I really do not see how i would get around this.